# SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.7.85

Tags: eclipse, db2

Any idea of how to connect to db2 in an sql file in an Eclipse application? 
I spent hours on trying to connect db2 using the following statement without any luck

```
[CONNECT'jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DB2ADMIN;create=true;user=db2admin;password=db2admin']
```

What I'm typing wrong?

I can ping the db and I can create tables but can not connect to it into my application
please help....

Comment: This doesn't at all look like a valid SQL statement. Basically, you should connect _before_ issuing any SQL statements or executing an SQL script in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about your connection string:

- Server: localhost
- Instance number: 50000
- Database name: *db2admin*
- Username: db2admin
- Password: db2admin

It is weird to have a database called db2admin.

What is the purpose of the 'create' option in the URL. I did not found that in the documentaion.

For more information about how to define the URL, please take a look at this page: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvdsprp.html